# MVC partial in modal posting wrong model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My partial view which is loaded into a bootstrap partial on my Index page, should be posting type `Announcement` but is posting type `AnnouncementViewModel` of the Index page model to the `Create` controller.

The `#modal-container` is specified in my _Layout, which is working as expected.

Unsure about the controllers - they appear correct, the problem is stemming from my ajax post I believe but I don't know what's the issue. I get the error after POST, however the database does update with the model correctly, but afterwards I get the below error.

I have specified `$('#create-container')`/`$('form')` as the form in which to serialize and send back to the controller.

Why is it doing this?

**Error:**

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AnnouncementsViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Announcement'.
```

**Index:**

```
@model AnnouncementsViewModel
<h2>Announcements</h2>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "Announcements", null, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-sm" })
    <div class="announcementTable">
        <div id="announcementList">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("List", Model.AnnouncementList);}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Partial:**

```
@model Announcement
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btn-create').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create","Announcements")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: $('#create-container').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success == true) {
                            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                            location.reload(false)
                        } else {
                            $('#modal-container').html(data);
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
            $('#btn-close').click(function () {
                $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
}
<div class="create-container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="newAnnouncementTableRow1">
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)</div>
            <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)</div>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Details)</div>
            <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Details)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="newAnnouncementTableRow2">
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDT)</div>
            <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDT)</div>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ExpiryDT)</div>
            <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExpiryDT)</div>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Enabled)</div>
            <div>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Enabled, 1)Yes
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Enabled, 0, new { @checked = "checked" })No
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="btn-create" class="btn btn-sm">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" data-dissmiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var avm = new AnnouncementsViewModel
            {
                AnnouncementList = new List<Announcement>()
            };
            avm.AnnouncementList = GetAnnouncementList();
            return View(avm);
        }
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return PartialView("Create");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Announcement a)
        {
            db.DbAnnouncement.Add(a);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Index();
        }
```

Comment: Please change this line `@{Html.RenderPartial("List", Model.AnnouncementList);}` with this `@{Html.Partial("List", Model.AnnouncementList);}` and try again.

Comment: Why? That would stop the list from being generated, which works, the issue is with creating a new announcement and returning to the Index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `contentType: 'application/json'` it your `.ajax()` call but returning View from Controller. Either change `contentType` to `html` or change controller to return `JsonResult` and `return Json("yourData");`

I recommend you to change your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    /* other data */
    dataType : "html",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    /* other data */
    success: function (data) {
        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        location.reload(false)
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
    {
        $('#modal-container').html(data);
    }
    /* other data */
});
```

Thing is response from server in your case always success but it returns **html** rather than **json** so you just don't have `data.success` at all.

The other issue as mentioned in the comments was that the controller was redirecting to an action method that it could not.

Changing `return Index();` to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Announcements");` solved the error and the redirecting to the Create partial page caused by using `return View();`.

Comment: Thanks, but with those changes (which make sense), I am still getting the same error. Should I be setting data: as `$('form')` or `$('#idofdivencasingform')`?

Comment: @PurpleSmurph as I remember it's not nessesory. If DbChanges works well - there are no problems with mapping. Your have problem with response that `ajax()` handles. I will update my answer shortly

Comment: Still the same error that the viewmodel is being sent to the controller. I'm guessing the issue is that the button is causing both the Index and the modal partial forms to post back, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Your problem is `return Index();` that uses different ViewModel. Write `return View();`

Comment: Hurah! That does stop the error but redirects to Create partial despite location.reload(false) thank you.